# How to put svg in one line with text file

Tags: html, css, svg, tailwind-css, styling

The svg file is on another line, i need it to be right next to the word

`<h1 className="text-8xl text-center text-white font-extrabold mb-10"> Take Your Ne <span style={{ display: "inline" }}> <img src={xLetter.src} alt="X" /> </span> t Adventure To The Extreme </h1>`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lhaH.jpg)

Comment: It should be. Perhaps there is no enough space.

Comment: You can try wrapping the word next in a span, making it inline-flex and sizing your image  appropriately like here https://play.tailwindcss.com/xy1AcH1J0p

Answer (score 0):

in tailwindcss you can use this code

```
 <div class="flex items-center justify-center mx-4">
    <p> Take Your Ne</p>
    <img src="link" alt="logo" class="mx-4" />
    </div>
```